# How can I log Ruby-watir-cucumber results in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: ruby, excel, cucumber, watir, resultset

I am using Ruby-watir-cucumber for automation. Till now I was using .csv to log my results of the batch run. Now my requirement has changed and i want to log the results in an excel sheet. My Code to log result in .csv file is as follows:

```
  day = Time.now.strftime("%v")
  dirname = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
  File.open('../../Results'+day+'.csv','a+') do |file|
  file.puts("#{dirname},#{scenario_name},Pass,#{Time.now}")
  end
```

Please help me to modify the code to log my results in an excel.

In the complete batch, I have around 100 scenarios which am running. I also need to use multiple tabs. I also tried using spreadsheet gem but it isnt working for me.

Comment: Why can't you just load the CSV into Excel?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to log the result into different tabs when I am using it for different browsers. Earlier I was working on firefox only, so csv worked for me. Now i need to log in excel, with different tabs for different browsers.

Comment: Your question is rather broad - ie you are asking for someone to pick a library and describe how to do a whole bunch of things with it. Please consider picking a gem, trying it out and then asking a specific question. For example, you could show what you tried with the spreadsheet gem and ask a specific question about addressing the "isn't working for me" part.